# How to resolve coordinates of selected objects

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I need to get coordinates of selected objects in indesign project. It would be probably some javascript code to do this.

Goal is, to have all objects with their coordinates exported to xml or any other format I can work further with.

Answer (score 1):

An idml export would provide all the info you need. However it would require a good understanding of IDML syntax.
A snippet export woukld provide good informations too, easier to read than the whole IDML stuff but yet limited per object.

A script can also output the informations you need but it am not aware of an existing one. Fact is that inspite the appearances, getting the "corrdinates" may need serious computations are items could be rotated a/o skewed thus affecting the global bounds.

You should investigate Adobe Scripting Forum. I guess this kind of needs have already been exposed there.